# Unable to set the text for UITextfield from other class

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to set the text for the `UITextField` in the `SecondViewController` from the `FirstViewController` using the below code:

```
// First ViewController
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
    viewController?.sampleTxtField?.text = "world"
    if let navigator = self.navigationController {
        navigator.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

```
// Second ViewController
 @IBOutlet weak var sampleTxtField: UITextField?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("the textfield value is,\(String(describing: sampleTxtField?.text))")
}
```

In the log I am getting: `"the textfield value is,Optional("")"`

I think I am doing some silly mistake. I checked many questions but I am unable find any solution.

Comment: It will crash probably. Controls will not be initialized until its controller get loaded. Try passing the text only and set the value in `viewDidLoad:` method.

Comment: @bcr The only `optional` is saving him till now. It will be crash if he will use `!` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong.

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
    viewController?.sampleTxtField?.text = "world"
```

In above statment, view's not get loaded in UI so `sampleTxtField` always will be nil, Instead create a property in SecondVC, `var sample : String?` and assign it as above. Then in SecondVC's viewDidload, assign the value as `textField.text = sample`

```
// First ViewController

@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController
    viewController?.sample = "world"
    if let navigator = self.navigationController {
        navigator.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    }
}
```

// Second ViewController

```
@IBOutlet weak var sampleTxtField: UITextField?
var sample : String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
sampleTxtField.text =  sample
    print("the textfield value is,\(String(describing: sampleTxtField?.text))")
}
```

Comment: @R.Mohan You can but after loading the controller not by just initializing it.

Comment: @R.Mohan What do you mean by directly? Before loading from other's VC?

Comment: yes, i will do like this in objective c, but in swift we need a variable to pass the value ?

Answer (score 1):

Make a variable in second viewController like this :

```
var sampleText: String!
```

And in `viewDidLoad()` of the second view controller write this:

```
sampleTxtField?.text = sampleText
```

and in first view controller replace `viewController?.sampleTxtField?.text = "world"` line with this:

```
viewController.sampleText = "world"
```

This is the standard way to set a value to a textField from another class.

Comment: Actually you can, for this you should make a textField and set it as sampleTextField like this:


`let textField = UITextField()
textField.text = "world"
viewController?.sampleTxtField = textField`

But its not a good job From the perspective encapsulation. All the thing the second viewController wants is a text, but instead you give it a textField!! Did you get the point?

Comment: Ok, i understand. will do as you mentioned in the answer. Thank you for the clear explanation :)

Comment: You're welcome, and I would appreciate it if you accept my answer if you liked it.

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a UIViewController from storyboard using `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)` method it creates a new instance of ViewController and returns it but the UIView and it's elements are not initialised until the UIView is loaded in memory.

> ViewDidLoad() gets called when the view controller’s content view (the
>   top of its view hierarchy) is created and loaded from a storyboard.
>   The view controller’s outlets are guaranteed to have valid values by
>   the time this method is called.

So you need to configure your UI element values in ViewDidLoad to have a proper value to these elements.

In you case `viewController?.sampleTxtField?.text = "world"` line will not work as Views not yet loaded in memory. To resolve this you need to define a String variable and assign the value after the ViewController is initialised. Then in ViewDidLoad you can assign the String value to the UITextField text property.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var sampleTxtField: UITextField!
   var sampleText: String? //it can be var also with default value

   func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     //assign the textField Value here
     if let text = sampleText {
        self.sampleTxtField.text = text 
     }
   }
}
```

Now in `FirstViewController` you can assign the sampleText property like

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let secondViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as? SecondViewController else {
      fatalError("No ViewController with Identifier "SecondViewController")
    }
    secondViewController.sampleText = "world"
    if let navigator = self.navigationController {
        navigator.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation @suhit, I understant it very clearly Thank you :)